# Is there a solution based on NodeJS for converting STEP files (.step, .stp) into STL (.stl) format?

Tags: web-apps, javascript, node.js, 3d, cad

Is there a solution based on NodeJS (or alternatively any javascript library) for converting STEP files (.step, .stp) into STL (.stl) format or any other WebGL-friendly format (.gltf, .obj, etc…) to display the 3D files in the browser?

The intended use is to convert the file immediately after they are uploaded by the user. For this reason, converting them manually is not an option.

The conversion issue has been discussed at length in the past in several threads, this one probably the most relevant: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/7125 . Besides being 4 years old, a series of solution have been suggested using Python libraries (e.g. pythonocc) or external standalone software, while there is no mention to a valid solution for Javascript (Clara.io requires to set up an account, binding you to their terms and condition + sending to an external third-party private files + it doesn't look like it's being mantained).

Node-occ (https://github.com/OpenWebCAD/node-occ) could represent a potential solution, however, at this moment is poorly maintained and not possible to install (or compile from source) both on Windows or Linux, as discussed in the several issues opened recently on the repo.